# Detect filetype in narrowed region

Tags: vim, php, xml, vim-plugins

I am using the terrific [NrrwRgn](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3075) plugin. I often edit XML files with PHP in CDATA sections, so in the narrowed buffer I get this:

```
<![CDATA[                        
$foo='bar';
doSomething($foo);
            ]]>
```

How can I have the narrowed region identified as PHP when it is PHP and as XML or something else when it is something else? Note that even in this example, by selecting the PHP section with `vit\nr` the CDATA tags are still there, so technically this is not-well-formed XML, not PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution to this problem so I settled for

```
nnoremap <leader>js set ft=javascript
```

I, too, am curious for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure, I completely understand what you want. The NrrwRgn plugin should automatically set the filetype of the narrowed window to that of the original buffer. If this is not what you want, you can however hook into NrrwRgn command on creation and closing of the windows. So here is what you could do:

Create a file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/php.vim` (create non-existing directories, on Windows, this would be `$VIM/vimfiles/after/ftplugin/php.vim`, where $VIM is whatever directory vim tells you, when issuing `:echo $VIM`) and put into it:

```
let g:nrrw_custom_options={}
let g:nrrw_custom_options['filetype']='php'
```

And in your `.vimrc` you put this:

```
let b:nrrw_aucmd_close= "unlet! g:nrrw_custom_options"
```

That should be all that needs to be setup and then whenever you narrow something from a php file, it will be automatically be set to filetype php.

Make sure filetype plugins are enabled so (you do this, by putting something like
`filetype plugin on` into your `.vimrc`.

Comment: Thank you. The original buffer is XML and I am editing PHP that was in a CDATA section of the XML. I will try your solution and write back. Thanks.